# Html5+mediaelement.js audio stream, onprogress not updated on chrome and IE7-8

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I have this project of a webplayer in HTML 5 that reads infinite streams using media elements (for fallback capabilities).
I got a solution that can play the audio fine, but I have a hard time showing the loaded bytes progress.

I added a eventListener on the progress event in media elements.  (putting it on the audio element directly breaks in IE 7-8)
I can see it is called every x seconds.
But on chrome and IE 7-8, it seems like the values returned are stuck after the first value encountered.
So that every iteration of onprogress will always return the same value after the first call.

Here is my code:

```
function activateMediaElement(){
    /*
    param mode:
    // auto: attempts to detect what the browser can do
    // auto_plugin: prefer plugins and then attempt native HTML5
    // native: forces HTML5 playback
    // shim: disallows HTML5, will attempt either Flash or Silverlight
    // none: forces fallback view
    */

    $('#audio-player').mediaelementplayer({
        alwaysShowControls: false,      
        //mode: 'native', //-- native messes up IE 7-8 -- actually, not needed...
        plugins: ['flash','silverlight'],
        features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
        audioVolume: 'horizontal',
        //enablePluginDebug:true,
        flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
        silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',
        audioWidth: 472,
        //audioHeight: 70,
        //iPadUseNativeControls: true,
        //iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
        //AndroidUseNativeControls: true,
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {  

            mediaElement.addEventListener('progress', function(e) { 
                setProgressBar(e);
            }, false);

            //[...]
        },
        error: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            audioError('me error');
        },
        customError: msg.search_for_valid_format
    }); 

}

function setProgressBar(e){
    //show the progress for the current show
    if(current_show.startphp > 0 && current_show.endphp > 0){
        var bufferedTime = getBufferedTime(e);          
        var percent = (bufferedTime - current_show.startphp) *100 / (current_show.endphp-current_show.startphp);
        if(percent > 100){
            percent = 100;  
        }
        $(".timeline-buffered").css('width', percent+'%');
    }
}
function getBufferedTime(e){    
    //borrowed from mediaelement.js 
    var target = (e != undefined) ? e.target : $(mejs)[0],
    var buffered = 0;

    // newest HTML5 spec has buffered array (FF4, Webkit)
    if (target && target.buffered && target.buffered.length > 0 && target.buffered.end && target.duration) {
        // TODO: account for a real array with multiple values (only Firefox 4 has this so far) 
        buffered = target.buffered.end(0);
    } 
    // Some browsers (e.g., FF3.6 and Safari 5) cannot calculate target.bufferered.end()
    // to be anything other than 0. If the byte count is available we use this instead.
    // Browsers that support the else if do not seem to have the bufferedBytes value and
    // should skip to there. Tested in Safari 5, Webkit head, FF3.6, Chrome 6, IE 7/8.
    else if (target && target.bytesTotal != undefined && target.bytesTotal > 0 && target.bufferedBytes != undefined) {
        buffered = target.bufferedBytes;
    }
    // Firefox 3 with an Ogg file seems to go this way
    else if (e && e.lengthComputable && e.total != 0) {
        buffered = e.loaded;
    }

    //let's consider the buffered value like seconds
    var bufferedTime = pls.startTime+buffered;
    return bufferedTime;
}
```

So on every call of onprogress, I can see that the buffered value is always the same. (either 0 on the mobile chrome/IE 7-8 or a small value below 1 on the desktop version of chrome).
I have read many solutions on the web which all lead to using target.buffered.end(0);. But those solutions are pretty much 3-4 years old.

Am I missing something or is it really just impossible to do?

Comment: Got any solution for this problem?